# How can I filter the results of my embedsMany relation?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent

I'm having difficulty with this concept.

I have a `User` class that `hasMany` of class `OrganizationUser`.

My `OrganizationUser` class `embedsMany` of class `Notification`.

In my code, I can return the `User`'s `OrganizationUsers` by doing:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->organizationUsers;
return $user;
```

This returns a property `organization_users` on my `user` object that is an array of `OrganizationUsers`.

Now, I would like to return the `Notifications` of each `OrganizationUser`.

At first, I did the following, which worked fine:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->organizationUsers;
for ($i = 0; $i < $user->organizationUsers->count(); $i++) {
    $user->organizationUsers[$i]->notifications;
}
return $user;
```

This would attach a `notifications` array on each object in my `organization_users` array.

However, I would like to filter these results by my `resolved` property.

I have tried the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $user->organizationUsers->count(); $i++) {
    $user->organizationUsers[$i]->notifications->where('resolved', false)->get();
}
```

However, this does not filter at all. I tried doing:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $user->organizationUsers->count(); $i++) {
    $user->organizationUsers[$i]->notifications = 
         $user->organizationUsers[$i]->notifications->where('resolved', false)->get();
}
```

But this does not return an array in the way that I'd hoped, instead, the notifications array is "indexed":

```
notifications: {
    4: 
        {
        _id: "560ab1639a3709120400432e"
        created_at: "2015-09-29 15:42:27"
        resolved: false
        type: "New User Request"
        updated_at: "2015-09-29 15:42:27"
        }
}
```

It seems to be returning an object of objects instead of an array of objects. Any thoughts?